# Omit .d.ts Imports Files when Emitting to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser, typescript-typings, tsconfig

I have a library that is being loaded from the browswer using a `script` tag. I am using a .d.ts implementation for the library so that I would have type checking. I am importing one of the classes from the library and using it as a constructor. Here is the problem, I don't want to have the import statment in the emitted JavaScript files because I am already loading the library from a `script` tag, so I don't need to import the things from the library.

How do I not include the imports when emitting a the JavaScript files?

I tried setting `module` in the `tsconfig` to `None`, but that just uses `CommonJS` import.

Comment: Could you add your tsconfig configuration?

Comment: You don't have to `import` a `.d.ts` file to use type declarations.

Comment: @Kokodoko then how do I use type checking without importing the declarations?

Comment: VS Code should automatically detect `.d.ts` files in your project. `import` is only used to import actual code, so that should still work on the javascript side.